# Zoomed image on background, sharp image on the front

Tags: html, css, layout, background, zooming

I'm working to get an effect similar to this, whit a zoomed and blurry image on the background, and the same but in normal size on the front. Like the image below.
[This effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHzfg.png)

Now i have this situation:

```css
.mySlides {
    display: none;
    height: 15vw;
}

.imageslide{/*
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;*/
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-filter:blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px);
  
        display: block; 
}
```

```html
<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="WEB-IMG/P4A_OST Cover.jpg" class="imageslide"/>
 </div>
```

I want to use 2  tag for this, because i don't wanna set the backround for the parent div. Anyway this isn't the problem for now. I used

```
transform: scale(1.1);
```

But the effect is very ugly and the image is out of the bounds o f the parent. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I get a good result doing this.

```css
.imageslide{   
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 600%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}

.cover{
    width: 13vw;
    height: 13vw;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    
}

.mySlides {
    display: none;
    height: 15vw;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="WEB-IMG/P4A_OST Cover.jpg" class="imageslide"/>
  <img src="WEB-IMG/P4A_OST Cover.jpg" class="cover"/>
 </div>
```